# Bind rows of two tables if they have different values in column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
Type   value 
1    Error: unexpected
2    Warning message
3    invalid factor
```

and:

```
Type      value 
10    In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "v1")
34    Warning message
3     nvalid factor level
```

So as you see row 2 in df2 has same value as second row in df1. So desired result is:

```
Type   value 
1    Error: unexpected
2    Warning message
3    invalid factor
10    In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "v1")
3     invalid factor level
```

How could i do that. i know function bind_row(), but how to use it with that condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to bind the dataset with `bind_rows` after making the column names same i.e. Type in second dataset is changed to ID, then we get the `distinct` rows based on the 'value' column

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
     rename(ID = Type) %>%
     bind_rows(df1, .) %>%
     distinct(value, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#  ID                                        value
#1  1                            Error: unexpected
#2  2                              Warning message
#3  3                               invalid factor
#4 10 In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "v1")
#5  3                         invalid factor level
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, value = c("Error: unexpected", "Warning message", 
"invalid factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))

df2 <- structure(list(Type = c(10L, 34L, 3L), 
value = c("In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = \"v1\")", 
"Warning message", "invalid factor level")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, you can combine the two dataframes and keep only rows with unique `value` in it.

```
names(df1)[1] <- 'Type'
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
df3[!duplicated(df3$value), ]

#  Type                                        value
#1    1                            Error: unexpected
#2    2                              Warning message
#3    3                               invalid factor
#4   10 In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "v1")
#6    3                         invalid factor level
```